problems with batch in firestore
I have a folder inside firestore with a list of uids. I want that when the user creates a new event, a new firestore "notifications" folder is created located in each uid of the user. I have created this code but it does not work for me, please Can you help me!!
thank you
Future<void> crearNotificaciones(String remitenteUid, String notificacionType) async {

final Uuid uuid = Uuid();

if (notificacionType == ConstantesNotificacionType.nuevoEvento) {

 try {
   final seguidressnapshot = await firebaseFirestore.collection(ConstantesFirebase.users).doc(remitenteUid).collection('seguidores').get();

   if (seguidressnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
     print('no segudires');
     return;
   }

   final batch = firebaseFirestore.batch();

   for (var doc in seguidressnapshot.docs) {
     final uid = doc.id;

     final notificacionCollection = firebaseFirestore.collection(ConstantesFirebase.users).doc(uid).collection(ConstantesFirebase.notificaciones);

     final notificacionID = uuid.v1();

     final newNotification = NotificacionesModel(
       notificacionId: notificacionID,
       remitentUid: remitenteUid,
       recibeUid: uid,
       notificacionType: notificacionType,
       notificadoA: Timestamp.now(),
       esVisto: false
     ).toJson();

     final docRef = notificacionCollection.doc(notificacionID);

     batch.set(docRef, newNotification, SetOptions(merge: true));
   }
   await batch.commit();
   print('notificacion enviada');

 } catch (e) {
   print("error $e");
 }
}

